# how can i put what i input on the box in the output. thank you

Tags: javascript, html

[where to put output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGYRJ.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFE2D.png)

cant put the entire code sorry on the body so i just put it on picture

Comment: Your submit button submits the form, which defaults to submitting to the same page and reloads the screen. Try using `type="button"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is preventing the page from loading and to do that, we pass the event object and use the preventDefault() method to stop the reload. Once that is done we grab the values of the input elements and use innerHTML to display it inside the

element with the help of the fancy template literals.

### Here's the button

```
<button onClick="handleSubmit(event)">Submit</button>
```

### Here's the JavaScript code

```
function handleSubmit (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let name = document.getElementById("fname").value
  let age = document.getElementById("age").value
  let email = document.getElementById("email").value
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `Name is : ${name} Age is: ${age} 
  and Email is : ${email}`;
}
```

### Here's the code pen for this

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/abdelhakguettaf/pen/NWweNKW?editors=1111/)

I would not recommend implementing my answer as it is very unpolished and might cause problems in the long run, but I hope it helps.